# Python: use range() function or np.arrange() as parameter arr[range(m), y]

Tags: python, arrays, deep-learning

This is what I saw in a blog:
(Source: https://deepnotes.io/softmax-crossentropy#cross-entropy-loss)

```
def delta_cross_entropy(X,y):
    """
    X is the output from fully connected layer (num_examples x num_classes)
    y is labels (num_examples x 1)
        Note that y is not one-hot encoded vector. 
        It can be computed as y.argmax(axis=1) from one-hot encoded vectors of labels if required.
    """
    m = y.shape[0]
    grad = softmax(X)
    grad[range(m),y] -= 1
    grad = grad/m
    return grad
```

Also I try it myself by replacing y(matrix) using a integer number:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])
print(arr)

arr[range(2), 1] = 0
print("after range: ", arr)
```

As result I got:

```
[[1 2 3]                                                                                                              
 [4 5 6]                                                                                                              
 [7 8 9]]    

after range:  [[1 0 3]                                                                                                
 [4 0 6]                                                                                                              
 [7 8 9]]
```

Can someone pls explain what does this range() function do here? thank you!

Comment: It is called [fancy indexing](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/02.07-fancy-indexing.html). You pass an array of indices (range(2) or [0, 1]) for one of the axes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`range(2)` is like passing `[0, 1]` as an argument in this case. You'll get the same result in this experiment:

```
arr1 = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])
arr1[range(2), 1] = 0
arr2 = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])
arr2[[0, 1], 1] = 0

np.all(arr1 == arr2)
```

Where `np.all` checks if the equality is true across the whole array and it will return `True`

In other words `arr[range(2), 1] = 0` is equal to this as well:

```
arr[0, 1] = 0
arr[1, 1] = 0
```

And another way to look at it:

```
for i in range(2):
    arr[i, 1] = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Range just creates a new range object from 0 to 1 less than the value given, so for example:

```
>>> range(2)
[0, 1]
```

Numpy arrays can accept iterables of indices to index so in this case you are saying "set the {0,1} row, 1st column equal to 0".